# TeamCity Basics

Tags: tfs, teamcity

I am trying out TeamCity for build integration for my project. I am completely new to this. I understand I need to install TeamCity in a server and by default it installs one agent also. I have all that completed until now. And I have MS TFS as Version controlling software on my local machine... and my question is how do I get TeamCity 'appear' in my VS projects? I mean do I have to install another Team City Build agent on my local development machine? is that how it works? thanks for any comments and info. Basically what I am asking is..
1) what do I need to do at the development local machine level that makes it 'connected' to TeamCity server or agents .. installed on the server.
2)Do I need to install Visual studio on the same server as TeamCity for the plugins to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what is exactly the question, but let me describe the workflow:

You installed the teamcity server on your buldserver, it created an agent as well.

The next thing you need to do is setup a teamcity project and build configuration. It is quite straitforward to make TeamCity check TFS (or any source control) for changes, check out and build a project.

TFS or Visual Studio does not need to know about TeamCity.

If you want to track the build status, you can check it in web interface or use TeamCity Tray Notifier (download link is available in TeamCity web interface).

If you need more build agents, the download link is available in web interface.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the information. that made it a clear...Do I need VS or .NET installed on the TeamCity server machine? and what is the VS studio plug in doing in all this?

Comment: The VS plugin is another possibility to trigger and monitor builds from IDE. We don't use it in our team: I think Tray notifier is a better option. On build server, you don't need VS installed, but .NET is a must, it contains MSBuild. You will lack the ".target" files for a build and it will fail. Instead of installing VS and spending a license, you can just copy .target files from dev machine to build server.

Comment: Do I need to install Build Agent in my local development machine?

Comment: No, you don't. Unless you have very frequent and long-running builds - in this case you may consider having multiple agents and build on many machines.

Comment: If the documentation says, installing a build agent in a separate machine other than the Build server is recommended. What does that mean? The 'other' machine is determined how? Why cannot it be my local machine ? any pros and cons?

Comment: Well, we use the same build and CI server and have no problems with that. There are pros for projects with long build time: in this case you don't load CI server, and different builds may run separately on different build agent. No profit for quickly building projects, though.

Answer (score 0):

1) What do I need to do at the development local machine level that makes it 'connected' to TeamCity server or agents .. installed on the server.

**Answer:** You don't need anything on the development local machine. You need to configure TeamCity to check your TFS repository on an interval or setup a trigger in TFS that will notify TeamCity of new code being checked in.

2) Do I need to install Visual studio on the same server as TeamCity for the plugins to work?

**Answer:** No, you don't need the full blown Visual Studio, but it might be the easiest thing to get everything working. You need at least the latest MS Build tools (at the moment Microsoft Build Tools 2015 from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159). You might also need the various SDKs (or parts of them) - Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 10 (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk), Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8 (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-8-sdk).